# Can GCP do port mirroring at the subnet level?

Tags: networking, google-compute-engine, packet-sniffer

Can I define a custom network in Google Cloud Platform in such a way so that I can get the equivalent behavior of [Port Mirroring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring) in my VPC as one would configure on a hardware switch?

The goal is to sniff all traffic in the VPC for the purpose of network debugging, or deploying an Network Intrusion Detection System.

I'm not looking to deploy a bastion host, or use NetFlow.

Answer (score 1):

No, not a mirrored port.

For visibility, you can bring your own security appliance VMs such as firewalls or virtual switches.  Or consume their flow logs. Security vendors with a public cloud story probably do one of these.

Edit: I know you said GCP, but compare to what Azure very recently announced,  [Virtual Network TAP](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-networking-fall-2018-update/). You could try this, then ask GCP if they plan to offer something equivilant.

Comment: This would require using a VM/scrurity appliance as a firewall for the VPC subnet, right?

Comment: Yes, you would have to route your own traffic through that VM like you would for a firewall.